# How to add a box plot and a vertical line in a histogram diagram in python Plotly Express graph objects subplots

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, visualization, plotly-express

Below is the data that is used to create the histogram subplot charts in ploty express graph objects.

[image]

Below code is used to create histogram subplot charts in ploty express graph objects.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

specs = [[{'type':'histogram'}, {'type':'histogram'},{'type':'histogram'}]]
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, specs=specs, subplot_titles=['<b> Millenials </b>',
                                                                 '<b> Generation X </b>',
                                                                 '<b> Boomers </b>'])


fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(             
              x=df[df['Generation']=='Millenials']['NumCompaniesWorked'],
              
              opacity = 0.5,
              marker_color = ['#455f66'] * 15
              ),1,1)


fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(             
              x=df[df['Generation']=='Generation X']['NumCompaniesWorked'],
              
              opacity = 0.5,
              marker_color = ['#455f66'] * 15
              ),1,2)


fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(             
              x=df[df['Generation']=='Boomers']['NumCompaniesWorked'],
              
              opacity = 0.5,
              marker_color = ['#455f66'] * 15
              ),1,3)

fig.update_layout(
                  showlegend=False, 
                  title=dict(text="<b> Histogram - <br> <span style='color: #f55142'> How to add the box plot and mean vertical line on each diagram </span></b> ",
                             font=dict(
                                        family="Arial",
                                        size=20,
                                        color='#283747')
                    ))  
fig.show()
```

And below is the output I get from the above code
[image]

How can I include the mean (Average) vertical line in a histogram diagrams as the mean values are,

- Millenials = 2.2
- Generation X = 3.4
- Boomers = 4.1

and a box plot above all 03 histogram diagrams.

*Which should look like the shown diagram below for all 03 histogram diagrams.*

[image]

Comment: Please add enough data to your question to reproduce this work and we can help you.

Comment: @Hamzah as requested, data values are been included. Hope there could be solution to the query above

Comment: Please add it by the following commends: `df.head(10).to_dict()` then copy and paste this dictionary.

Comment: Does this link help  https://plotly.com/python/distplot/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#original df
df = pd.DataFrame({'NumCompaniesWorked':list(range(10)),
       'Millenials':[139,407,54,57,55,32,35,28,17,24],
       'Generation X':[53,108,83,90,70,27,32,40,26,24],
       'Boomers':[5,6,9,12,14,4,3,6,6,4]})

#reorganizing df
dfs = []
for col in ['Millenials', 'Generation X', 'Boomers']:
    dfs.append(df[['NumCompaniesWorked', col]].rename(columns={col:'count'}).assign(Generation=col))
df = pd.concat(dfs)

#output
   NumCompaniesWorked  count    Generation
0                   0    139    Millenials
1                   1    407    Millenials
2                   2     54    Millenials
3                   3     57    Millenials
4                   4     55    Millenials
5                   5     32    Millenials
6                   6     35    Millenials
7                   7     28    Millenials
8                   8     17    Millenials
9                   9     24    Millenials
0                   0     53  Generation X
1                   1    108  Generation X
2                   2     83  Generation X
3                   3     90  Generation X
4                   4     70  Generation X
5                   5     27  Generation X
6                   6     32  Generation X
7                   7     40  Generation X
8                   8     26  Generation X
9                   9     24  Generation X
0                   0      5       Boomers
1                   1      6       Boomers
2                   2      9       Boomers
3                   3     12       Boomers
4                   4     14       Boomers
5                   5      4       Boomers
6                   6      3       Boomers
7                   7      6       Boomers
8                   8      6       Boomers
9                   9      4       Boomers


fig = px.histogram(df,
       x='NumCompaniesWorked',
       y='count',
       marginal='box',
       facet_col='Generation')

fig.add_vline(x=2.2, line_width=1, line_dash='dash', line_color='gray', col=1)
fig.add_vline(x=3.4, line_width=1, line_dash='dash', line_color='gray', col=2)
fig.add_vline(x=4.1, line_width=1, line_dash='dash', line_color='gray', col=3)

fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]